# objective c : my app crash randomly under iOS10 and Xcode 8

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, ios10

We have migrated an application from iOS8 to iOS10. and this crash sometimes. we don't have a realistic scenario to reproduce it all times. so it's difficult to identify the problem,... Can someone help me to fix this please ?

we are using restkit v0.27.2 for the web service

This is the stack trace from the iPad log:

```
Incident Identifier: NNNNNNNNNNNN-1F96-4638-B948-PPPPPPPPPPP
CrashReporter Key:   61e1682c9fdb6be981ff0e2a3082b2fda06dbe5a
Hardware Model:      iPad6,12
Process:             myApp [952]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/SSSSSSSSS-1F96-4638-B948-LLLLLLLLLLLLLLL/myApp.app/myApp
Identifier:          be.myappTest.myApp
Version:             1 (1.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           be.myappTest.myApp [459]


Date/Time:           2017-09-06 15:35:49.1386 +0200
Launch Time:         2017-09-06 15:15:41.9749 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.2 (14F90)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000edef03ea
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1b1c4dd6 objc_msgSend + 22
1   CoreData                        0x1dec5f6b _PF_ManagedObject_WillChangeValueForKeyIndex + 395
2   CoreData                        0x1dec5d1d _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 175
3   myApp                       0x0006718f -[MyClassA initView] (MyClassA.m:119)
4   myApp                       0x00066fd3 -[MyClassA viewWillAppear:] (MyClassA.m:110)
5   UIKit                           0x2116c47d -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 393
6   UIKit                           0x2116c2cf -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 141
7   UIKit                           0x211ce47f -[UIViewController viewWillMoveToWindow:] + 453
8   UIKit                           0x2115cda5 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 561
9   UIKit                           0x21150bb1 __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke + 77
10  UIKit                           0x21150adb -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 417
11  UIKit                           0x21150bd1 __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke + 109
12  UIKit                           0x21150adb -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 417
13  UIKit                           0x21150bd1 __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke + 109
14  UIKit                           0x21150adb -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 417
15  UIKit                           0x21150bd1 __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke + 109
16  UIKit                           0x21150adb -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 417
17  UIKit                           0x2115c19d -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 439
18  UIKit                           0x2115bfd3 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 731
19  myApp                       0x00082b4b -[MyClassD addSubview:] (MyClassD.m:94)
20  myApp                       0x0004fa21 __50-[MyClassB next:]_block_invoke (MyClassB.m:218)
21  myApp                       0x000465ef __51-[MyClassC launch:failure:]_block_invoke (MyClassC.m:27)
22  myApp                       0x000eda95 __66-[RKObjectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke.229 (RKObjectRequestOperation.m:445)
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b5fd797 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b5fd783 _dispatch_client_callout + 23
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b601d05 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 903
26  CoreFoundation                  0x1beebd69 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
27  CoreFoundation                  0x1bee9e19 __CFRunLoopRun + 849
28  CoreFoundation                  0x1be3d1af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 471
29  CoreFoundation                  0x1be3cfd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
30  GraphicsServices                0x1d5e7b41 GSEventRunModal + 81
31  UIKit                           0x211b8e13 UIApplicationMain + 151
32  myApp                       0x0004189f main (main.m:16)
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x1b62a4eb start + 3

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1b6e8900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x1beebbe3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 145
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1beea065 __CFRunLoopRun + 1437
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1be3d1af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 471
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1be3cfd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   Foundation                      0x1c791ab5 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 259
6   Foundation                      0x1c7ae72d -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 87
7   UIKit                           0x21aba939 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 129
8   Foundation                      0x1c8758ab __NSThread__start__ + 1123
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b493b _pthread_body + 217
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b485d _pthread_start + 235
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b2468 thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:  GAIThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1b6e8900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x1beebbe3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 145
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1beea065 __CFRunLoopRun + 1437
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1be3d1af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 471
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1be3cfd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   Foundation                      0x1c791ab5 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 259
6   Foundation                      0x1c7ded79 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 81
7   myApp                       0x00176c89 +[GAI threadMain:] + 65
8   Foundation                      0x1c8758ab __NSThread__start__ + 1123
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b493b _pthread_body + 217
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b485d _pthread_start + 235
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b2468 thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1b6e9d4c write + 8
1   myApp                       0x0014cd4b CLSMachExceptionServer + 211
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b493b _pthread_body + 217
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b485d _pthread_start + 235
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b2468 thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1b6e8900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x1beebbe3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 145
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1beea065 __CFRunLoopRun + 1437
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1be3d1af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 471
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1be3cfd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   CFNetwork                       0x1c51a393 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 403
6   Foundation                      0x1c8758ab __NSThread__start__ + 1123
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b493b _pthread_body + 217
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b485d _pthread_start + 235
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b2468 thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:  AFRKNetworking
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1b6e8900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x1beebbe3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 145
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1beea065 __CFRunLoopRun + 1437
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1be3d1af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 471
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1be3cfd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   Foundation                      0x1c791ab5 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 259
6   Foundation                      0x1c7ded79 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 81
7   myApp                       0x000e08ab +[AFRKURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFRKURLConnectionOperation.m:190)
8   Foundation                      0x1c8758ab __NSThread__start__ + 1123
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b493b _pthread_body + 217
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b485d _pthread_start + 235
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b2468 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1b6fe73c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b245c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b2454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b2454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1b7b2454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x14fe7410    r1: 0x1e0ae2b2      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000001
    r4: 0x00000001    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x004760a4      r7: 0x00476588
    r8: 0x25d2bc55    r9: 0xedef03ea     r10: 0x016c87c0     r11: 0x161cb400
    ip: 0x00004232    sp: 0x00476080      lr: 0x1deb76e9      pc: 0x1b1c4dd6
  cpsr: 0x20000030

Binary Images:
0x3c000 - 0x25bfff myApp armv7  <96e545676dde3ce5972911df306b17c4> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/SSSSSSSSS-1F96-4638-B948-LLLLLLLLLLLLLLL/myApp.app/myApp
0x30c000 - 0x337fff dyld armv7s  <f0f6706c72713272afd9a5f6ec9b6071> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1b148000 - 0x1b149fff libSystem.B.dylib armv7s  <ba46299563c036628b1112a3d581de26> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x1b14a000 - 0x1b195fff libc++.1.dylib armv7s  <818c230dfc88357ab249302107b831f0> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1b196000 - 0x1b1affff libc++abi.dylib armv7s  <33f0c699025730d4b0ad607272fe7ddb> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1b1b0000 - 0x1b586fff libobjc.A.dylib armv7s  <233c8b2bca853098ac1d022d34bdcc3b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1b587000 - 0x1b58bfff libcache.dylib armv7s  <f4d5d994daa132689d3520c20272e323> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x1b58c000 - 0x1b594fff libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7s  <2f049d3ffb4f3877a8bbe39768a9499d> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x1b595000 - 0x1b59dfff libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7s  <b0a85cc0218b3fae90e7d9b8235cbfb6> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x1b59e000 - 0x1b5a4fff libcopyfile.dylib armv7s  <b1e1c5714d5d3a1c90186be3f81fc242> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x1b5a5000 - 0x1b5fbfff libcorecrypto.dylib armv7s  <4fbf71e0ff623025968dab336c251900> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1b5fc000 - 0x1b626fff libdispatch.dylib armv7s  <9ab8ace00b9837ddad453d0129d1d5a5> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1b627000 - 0x1b62afff libdyld.dylib armv7s  <60e884ce36b237e69d9eef4552b1f824> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x1b62b000 - 0x1b62bfff libkeymgr.dylib armv7s  <6761b1b654d03573aec33ba022be5c94> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x1b62c000 - 0x1b62cfff liblaunch.dylib armv7s  <839bfc6e0a2d361892f7d3a6068356df> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x1b62d000 - 0x1b631fff libmacho.dylib armv7s  <68bd5fa215ed3a70965933c295018f1d> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x1b632000 - 0x1b633fff libremovefile.dylib armv7s  <3f35771a5a3f3263b9f2a5adc4dfb8a7> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x1b634000 - 0x1b646fff libsystem_asl.dylib armv7s  <1ea9794c06bb3502b1bc3b7d925645a9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x1b647000 - 0x1b647fff libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7s  <b6b9673c843e3d2d8eadda86de4a3e5c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1b648000 - 0x1b6a8fff libsystem_c.dylib armv7s  <95ded7c071803a65ab5ca3b6145c728c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1b6a9000 - 0x1b6acfff libsystem_configuration.dylib armv7s  <a75984d7a2953e6dac099136a416a353> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x1b6ad000 - 0x1b6b1fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib armv7s  <ba09ede257f638729d2e54e565b55f7a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x1b6b2000 - 0x1b6b3fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib armv7s  <4c832d0f38b733d39d28b2cea9a2992b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x1b6b4000 - 0x1b6c6fff libsystem_coretls.dylib armv7s  <b4fc98b040ad3b8f8152b31c4470797c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x1b6c7000 - 0x1b6ccfff libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7s  <ae57924462d032b4b96eaadcf8104c95> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x1b6cd000 - 0x1b6e7fff libsystem_info.dylib armv7s  <30fbe279049d3a87abee2b409a89d5b0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x1b6e8000 - 0x1b703fff libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7s  <6b92f3110b5c3bc885fe467c2a31abcc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1b704000 - 0x1b733fff libsystem_m.dylib armv7s  <3794730a531232d78ca193c6a902cd0e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x1b734000 - 0x1b749fff libsystem_malloc.dylib armv7s  <96aa1913594c3dfabac04e1152afaba4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x1b74a000 - 0x1b799fff libsystem_network.dylib armv7s  <865cebaa38e2313d98807e9a36330a30> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x1b79a000 - 0x1b7a2fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib armv7s  <c6aeefd29e6f33abb0394339781b36a0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x1b7a3000 - 0x1b7aafff libsystem_notify.dylib armv7s  <31ff4f97dee73f54ada5e457c248f88d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x1b7ab000 - 0x1b7b0fff libsystem_platform.dylib armv7s  <44000c4ca0e23fe38c456ef3bc329eea> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x1b7b1000 - 0x1b7b9fff libsystem_pthread.dylib armv7s  <168117cfb548364289569c1f17089d14> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1b7ba000 - 0x1b7bcfff libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7s  <70ece4905b003adf99b6736d593468b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x1b7bd000 - 0x1b7c3fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib armv7s  <950e0821a00730bb934c2c0123704751> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x1b7c4000 - 0x1b7d4fff libsystem_trace.dylib armv7s  <c16150d86d6a3160bd84bed2229ebbdc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1b7d5000 - 0x1b7d5fff libunwind.dylib armv7s  <1af55cb8d4fe3d4682905b05f4f72f8d> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x1b7d6000 - 0x1b7d6fff libvminterpose.dylib armv7s  <c9e56af986da3a8994d370df9a1a14c6> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x1b7d7000 - 0x1b7f5fff libxpc.dylib armv7s  <3c374372415c3e7b94102c9a31d225c2> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x1b7f6000 - 0x1b990fff libicucore.A.dylib armv7s  <867a7d188c103933802e4ff1c169e941> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x1b991000 - 0x1b99dfff libz.1.dylib armv7s  <cb8a08f915e53d54a9599507ba811c88> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x1be35000 - 0x1c16dfff CoreFoundation armv7s  <acedaa6318293afa8cc249f6e92eb254> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1c16e000 - 0x1c17afff libbsm.0.dylib armv7s  <6d6c994a7053373895912e21a42aa88c> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x1c17b000 - 0x1c17bfff libenergytrace.dylib armv7s  <d19c13c5c5cd3931bdf756b539e84d68> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x1c17c000 - 0x1c1dffff IOKit armv7s  <55413dcb50f831478a04caf3447ba5f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x1c1e0000 - 0x1c1fcfff libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7s  <6b53cf3abfbd3018a2123c6dd4af58e5> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x1c1fd000 - 0x1c2affff libxml2.2.dylib armv7s  <aa7041e7ce163ed688da0b0342e8353b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x1c2b0000 - 0x1c32afff Security armv7s  <01c74100672a3a6791023ddfce3ecbd4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x1c32b000 - 0x1c384fff SystemConfiguration armv7s  <eb38914c3d193b7ea33814d6a1a587e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x1c385000 - 0x1c45cfff libsqlite3.dylib armv7s  <5b412ed381ed39439565bf1eb33f6088> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x1c45d000 - 0x1c72afff CFNetwork armv7s  <2a81c595c1cc395abdf76a3cbec50d08> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x1c72b000 - 0x1c735fff libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7s  <79541f1e64383072b3dbbaac16c828e9> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x1c736000 - 0x1c74bfff liblzma.5.dylib armv7s  <0b8324303764321fbc6c88138f58167e> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x1c74c000 - 0x1c761fff libCRFSuite.dylib armv7s  <886fbdbb89ee30c981b159961118ca1e> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1c762000 - 0x1c783fff libarchive.2.dylib armv7s  <219998deb9dd338eabb71bf270cb0cde> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x1c784000 - 0x1c785fff liblangid.dylib armv7s  <73a31c367ad93c0080c4084ac26b6d57> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x1c786000 - 0x1ca15fff Foundation armv7s  <e4a3c3cd0b243d0cb8ff73fc36c4b714> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1ca16000 - 0x1caf6fff libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <911b0f985b703b6e975b120eb723aea1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x1caf7000 - 0x1cdbdfff libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <9687d6b970bd312c826851e0902ef970> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x1cdbe000 - 0x1d04cfff vImage armv7s  <e52f9ee09f1f3610ae6da2cca23f2567> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x1d04d000 - 0x1d05ffff libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <4d0b7d86044032f995117c02fd7da6a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x1d060000 - 0x1d072fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib armv7s  <46b547093b323f7cb07b27ffc66bcf68> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x1d073000 - 0x1d087fff libSparseBLAS.dylib armv7s  <a760461002263f5788bb1cc4ac96e5c2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x1d088000 - 0x1d10bfff libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <26856a4a1ae533409076dccbe1873d32> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x1d10c000 - 0x1d10cfff vecLib armv7s  <3625b8bc1cb938288b9794bc6ce4c424> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x1d10d000 - 0x1d10dfff Accelerate armv7s  <09d82a9722f63dfe89dc7ac7d959b945> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x1d10e000 - 0x1d5ddfff CoreGraphics armv7s  <5c9c30c498dd3d8a9bd99b2a90e5acf7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x1d5de000 - 0x1d5effff GraphicsServices armv7s  <406bb820b2fd358d825d656249f1eded> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1d5f0000 - 0x1d633fff AppSupport armv7s  <dd936fa482453459b35a0b0b07228692> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x1d634000 - 0x1d744fff MobileCoreServices armv7s  <4bb718d4f3773e7aa7e8e1d0026a44f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x1d745000 - 0x1d79efff BaseBoard armv7s  <04954a0a26f437149769bb1f7155dcf6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x1d79f000 - 0x1d7acfff AssertionServices armv7s  <43a7b7bbda8c3689b249e52dc462cca4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x1d7ad000 - 0x1d7d6fff BackBoardServices armv7s  <2081a32ba62d3577b30ed7ccb1a906fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x1d7db000 - 0x1d823fff FrontBoardServices armv7s  <4c684ac3a2d030c598c2e2787340b6f0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x1d827000 - 0x1d853fff SpringBoardServices armv7s  <a59a8dc5832f38e88692d0864b7b9165> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x1d854000 - 0x1d869fff MobileKeyBag armv7s  <49d15f7df862344c9c7f287d101962d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x1d86a000 - 0x1d870fff IOSurface armv7s  <67b80ebb8e8435138e7ed1d4d69317ce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x1d871000 - 0x1d87bfff liblockdown.dylib armv7s  <ee6b362698aa3db4a39e314143c74e98> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x1d87c000 - 0x1d890fff CrashReporterSupport armv7s  <b6caf1972de833c5a080cd43335eafa8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x1d891000 - 0x1d893fff IOSurfaceAccelerator armv7s  <eefec1a8ba723ff69c5e52cc309e44dc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x1d894000 - 0x1d8cbfff AppleJPEG armv7s  <164a986737e432569a14f98550230d38> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x1d8cc000 - 0x1ddf7fff ImageIO armv7s  <de200c2776b03a9baa6beba31b07f465> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x1ddf8000 - 0x1ddfdfff TCC armv7s  <3146268e30bd313b9f8d497af363cae9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x1ddfe000 - 0x1de02fff AggregateDictionary armv7s  <f0d76ad8f1b530fc9929e16188312517> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x1de03000 - 0x1de0dfff PowerLog armv7s  <0626033ca8013d8d9fc57b9c559d30a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x1de0e000 - 0x1de6afff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib armv7s  <e84e0346eaa13332886f6f8ed4906473> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x1de6b000 - 0x1de7cfff CommonUtilities armv7s  <a0ffc2a014333a48a3800cbfe7f6cec9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x1de7d000 - 0x1de8dfff libcompression.dylib armv7s  <aa1e1032b7983b14a67182b2ed039e53> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x1de8e000 - 0x1e10cfff CoreData armv7s  <27852371a15f3ad5aa79f4373cd6103c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x1e10d000 - 0x1e111fff libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7s  <7c7fbb86aeca35cebfac0ec3d1965e9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x1e112000 - 0x1e116fff IOAccelerator armv7s  <25c61a760c463d1b921aa185edd72fd2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x1e117000 - 0x1e117fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7s  <4bd30f4eafba3d11a8926c5e7fa278a9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x1e118000 - 0x1e11afff libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7s  <b213e1c3a04b374ba70f6f65510cade0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x1e11b000 - 0x1e156fff libGLImage.dylib armv7s  <32b870e5fc25354080c13d2e244a0d89> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x1e157000 - 0x1e15ffff libGFXShared.dylib armv7s  <f93943bc87903d73b9f6c858ab4c4a75> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x1e160000 - 0x1e167fff IOMobileFramebuffer armv7s  <f10c67d19dc93905806b09ee1a82fd03> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x1e168000 - 0x1e168fff libmetal_timestamp.dylib armv7s  <7a27fe6d6eac3019b8aa2927bfdfcc0a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/libmetal_timestamp.dylib
0x1e169000 - 0x1e1bffff Metal armv7s  <f55994323cbd383d9c9ef7fde011fe23> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x1e1c0000 - 0x1e1c8fff OpenGLES armv7s  <dc60a7d691353916897fd2eb63f3424e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x1e1c9000 - 0x1e1e4fff CoreVideo armv7s  <11facca5b69f3f14b03ce69732290982> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x1e1e5000 - 0x1e1e7fff OAuth armv7s  <095fd453519730b9a9959b328a205ae8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x1e1e8000 - 0x1e21cfff Accounts armv7s  <f7ccccc915c1320da50d0955717a8c94> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x1e21d000 - 0x1e309fff libiconv.2.dylib armv7s  <71b914507d48327f83f6078d189d45ec> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x1e30a000 - 0x1e455fff CoreAudio armv7s  <bd3ea922b46d38939983383a6e469936> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x1e456000 - 0x1e459fff UserFS armv7s  <2fafff59896f3b3bbe65a96e556f8e8b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x1e45a000 - 0x1e537fff CoreMedia armv7s  <07057a9157e53356b41f82e3aac1f8de> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x1e538000 - 0x1e53dfff libcupolicy.dylib armv7s  <36f3a761e7c0387bb9e36d95bc939a47> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
0x1e53e000 - 0x1e5b4fff CoreTelephony armv7s  <f7ddb4809e2d3079a457777a4a72c765> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x1e5b5000 - 0x1e6b1fff libFontParser.dylib armv7s  <93c7009708f63e0cba6134c108b1560a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x1e6b2000 - 0x1e72dfff VideoToolbox armv7s  <21d49e99aa5b34d89e58d76003fddf71> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x1e72e000 - 0x1e72efff FontServices armv7s  <9aba5d8858013185bc5906dc7fff63e5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x1e72f000 - 0x1e84bfff CoreText armv7s  <aed4992a4a7d379da480e3302d4c64cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x1e84c000 - 0x1e863fff ProtocolBuffer armv7s  <7881f2f582483d6ea47478627de6a1db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x1e864000 - 0x1e88cfff PersistentConnection armv7s  <379a474e12e63d79b62e60ff61c9fb1e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x1e88d000 - 0x1e892fff DataMigration armv7s  <578b2897a9193445ac489effe6f76d32> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x1e893000 - 0x1ecb6fff AudioToolbox armv7s  <a175684c6f0b32b6b7e5fe02ea650b7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x1ecb7000 - 0x1ee64fff QuartzCore armv7s  <6fc564d06b643c2fa1098540c1de024a> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x1ee65000 - 0x1ee6afff Netrb armv7s  <45ab9318465630109e1fd036f6151980> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x1ee6b000 - 0x1ee78fff libcmph.dylib armv7s  <3e6a586936e831139589163f9e791d78> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x1ee79000 - 0x1ee95fff libmis.dylib armv7s  <e359fcc6079c39e7b8122879124ab1b5> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x1ee96000 - 0x1ef64fff LanguageModeling armv7s  <c63937acee1e31cd94d6c00549ac7a77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x1ef65000 - 0x1f03efff ManagedConfiguration armv7s  <492fc1f43a9239fc89aa31e81cf6f118> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x1f03f000 - 0x1f052fff libmarisa.dylib armv7s  <efc9ee8486033767a66a23219b2ad723> /usr/lib/libmarisa.dylib
0x1f053000 - 0x1f0fafff ProofReader armv7s  <6aebe575b2d23141a25d8bfa0e4202fc> 
....
```

Comment: [Edit] your question with the `initView` method of your `MyClassA` class and point out line 119.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I would say that one of your object or class is registering an observer on a Core Data object; the observing class/object gets released from memory without first unregistering the observer on the core data object.  When the core data object gets updated the notification gets sent to a released block of memory which causes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS/KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS.

To catch this, try to enable Zombies (see [How to enable NSZombie in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)).  Zombies keeps deallocated objects in memory but marked them as "zombies" so if a process attempts to access them after they are "released" from memory, at least you can get details of which object it is.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much @ekscrypto for your help ! I'll try this and keep you informed. I hop that I can reproduce the issue as quick as possible. Because the crash occurs only from time to time